# Qwt version conflict QTCREATOR

Tags: c++, qt, version, qt-creator, qwt

I'm having trouble deploying .exe generated with QtCreator on Ubuntu 14.04. I got several versions of qwt installed (and i need those, one compiled with qt4 the other with qt5). 
Problem is, i don't know why but Qt seems to link the wrong version of qwt to my .exe whatever i do .. When i use LDD on my .exe, it always show /usr/lib/libqwt.so.6. Thing is i'm linking the version i need in my .pro like this :

LIBS += -L/usr/local/qwt-6.1.2/lib/ -lqwt

And in project configuration i set LD_LIBRARY_PATH with /usr/local/qwt-6.1.2/lib

Still my .exe doesn't link to the right library.
Any idea why and how to fix this ? It causes segmentation fault on launch of course as my program is compiled with qt5 and not qt4.. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: By .exe you mean an application compiled on and for Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding a runtime path to the linker flags. In your .pro file you can add the following line (Its probably worth printing your QMAKE_LFLAGS in your pro file as well):

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += "-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/qwt-6.1.2/lib/"
message ("QMAKE_LFLAGS = $$QMAKE_LFLAGS")
```

Re-compile and then run ldd again. During runtime also ldd) your program should now point to this location first.

**Note**
This is assuming that you are using a gnu compiler!

Comment: I did try that though, and it doesn't work unfortunately. I use MinGW compiler, and ldd result is the same

Answer (score 0):

I sorted out my problem, seems like settings the environment variables in QtCreator is not enough. You have to do it in the terminal aswell before launching the .exe, that was my bad. 
Just had to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH correctly.